# How to add multiple relations one at a time in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

So i've been struggling with this for some time now, i have this many to many realtionship in my codebase. Between a User and Odds. I want the User to be able to add an Odds

User Entity:

```
 @Entity()
    @Unique(['username'])
    export class User extends BaseEntity {
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
      id: number;

      @Column()
      username: string;

      @Unique(['email'])
      @Column()
      email: string;

      @Column()
      password: string;

      @Column({ nullable: true })
      customerId: string;

      @ManyToMany(type => Odds, odds => odds.user)
      @JoinTable()
      odds: Odds[];

      @Column()
      salt: string;

      async validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
      const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, this.salt);
      return hash === this.password;
  }
}
```

Odds Entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Odds extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  hometeam: string;

  @Column()
  awayteam: string;

  @Column()
  hometeamLogo: string;

  @Column()
  awayteamLogo: string;

  @Column()
  bet: string;

  @Column({ type: 'real' })
  value: string;

  @Column()
  stake: number;

  @Column({ type: 'real' })
  bookieOdds: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.odds)
  user: User[];
}
```

When i try to add a relation like this

```
async addOddsToUser(user: User, oddsId: number): Promise<void> {
    const id = user.id;
    const userDB = await this.userRepository.findOne({ id });
    const odds = await this.oddsRepository.findOne({ id: oddsId });
    userDB.odds = [odds];
    userDB.save();
  }
```

In the associative table it does add the relation the first time, but if i add one more it overrides the first relation, i also tried userDB.odds.push(odds); which doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that your `addOddsToUser` function overrides the `userDB.odds` array with a new single array item each time. Thus existing relations will be deleted as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://typeorm.io/#/relations-faq/avoid-relation-property-initializers):

> When you save the object it will check if there are any categories in the database bind to the question - and it will detach all of them. Why? Because relation equal to [] or any items inside it will be considered like something was removed from it, there is no other way to check if an object was removed from entity or not.
>
> Therefore, saving an object like this will bring you problems - it will remove all previously set categories.